# How to see the results of a json

Tags: python

I want to run this api call which can open in a browser:
https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/users/2901002/reputation-history?page=600&pagesize=100&site=stackoverflow

I use this:

```
from stackapi import StackAPI
SITE = StackAPI('stackoverflow')
SITE.max_pages=10000000
SITE.page_size=100
post = SITE.fetch('/users/{ids}/reputation-history', ids=['59115355'])
```

How is it possible to see the result of json as in the link?

I would like to receive a specific user reputation history like this

```
https://stackoverflow.com/users/2901002/jezrael?tab=reputation
```

Comment: Isn't the result in the `post` variable?

Comment: @zvone I don't know how to print it?

Comment: What do you mean? Did you try `print(post)`? What does the `StackAPI` documentation say?

Comment: I tried print and I receive this `{'backoff': 0, 'has_more': False, 'page': 1, 'quota_max': 300, 'quota_remaining': 300, 'total': 0, 'items': []}` the documentation has an example for answers/{ids}/comments and I find this as example and used for reputation-history call. But it seems that it doesn;t work

Comment: @Nathalie id in you link vs API call in code is different, print is working fine and shoing zero results because for this id 59115355 no record is available.